# Why can't my terminal run icecast.xml code?

Tags: macos, terminal, icecast

I'm trying to launch an ice cast server by running the icecast.xml file in my terminal on Mac, I get the following errors

```
/Users/me/Desktop/Streaming/icecast-2.4.4/conf/icecast_minimal.xml: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/Users/me/Desktop/Streaming/icecast-2.4.4/conf/icecast_minimal.xml: line 2: `<icecast>'
```

Do I need to install it in an etc location or can I run it from the same directory it is in. My conclusion is that I installed the file in an inappropriate location.

Comment: What are you using as a command to "run" it?  XML isn't executable or a script...it's data.

Comment: @PhillipMills Im just calling the file path in terminal. I'm not sure how to get the file to execute since afterwards I need to run this command to start the server.           `sudo /etc/init.d/icecast start `

Comment: You need to start icecast _binary_ not the XML file itself, this way:
icecast -c <path_to_xml_config>

Comment: @AlexParamonov Hello Alex, it gives me this error `zsh: parse error near "\n"`